# Power BI using difference between dates and allocating them hours

Tags: date, powerbi

[image]

I have just started using power BI and I am having problems with the following:

This table has data refering to projects; each project has a set of hours allocated to them.

I want to know the nr of hours allocated to each project by year.

My problem is that some projects go on for over a year (the start date is the column START and the end date is the column END), I want to take the hours in column [quant] and divide them equally whithin the duration of the project. And after sum them by year.

I know the hours dedicated to the project...they are in column [quant]. For example for the project id 57156 I will have a total of 5 hours for that project, but the project starts in 13_04_2016 and ends in 01_01_2020. That means I will have to divide those 5 hours for that period. I need to find a way to divide my 5 hours for the project duration and them sum them by years.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kevlai22 I don't know if it helps you but I got the answer by using query editor and creating there a new colum and using the following formula: {Number.From([start])..Number.From([end])} then you get a column that has a list in each row and you just click expand and it creates new rows. Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

### If you need TotalHours between two dates

```
let
    t = #table({"a","b"},{{#date(2017,01,13),#date(2017,01,11)}}),
    TotalHours = Table.AddColumn(t,"TimeDifference", each Duration.TotalHours([a]-[b]))
in
    TotalHours
```

[image]

Comment: Exatcly. I can calculate the time difference between the dates. My problem is afterwards. With that number I need to divide the column [quant] by that number to get the hours I can use by month and them I need to allocate them to the years.